# mysql insert success but nothing is added

Tags: php, mysql, insert

look at this code

```
<?
require_once("conn.php");
require_once("includes.php");
require_once("access.php");

if(isset($_POST[s1]))
{
    //manage files
    if(!empty($_FILES[images]))
    {
        while(list($key,$value) = each($_FILES[images][name]))
        {
            if(!empty($value))
            {
                $NewImageName = $t."_".$value;
                copy($_FILES[images][tmp_name][$key], "images/".$NewImageName);

                $MyImages[] = $NewImageName;
            }
        }

        if(!empty($MyImages))
        {
            $ImageStr = implode("|", $MyImages);
        }
    }

    $q1 = "insert into class_catalog set 
                                MemberID = '$_SESSION[MemberID]',
                                CategoryID = '$_POST[CategoryID]',
                                Description = '$_POST[Description]',
                                images = '$ImageStr',
                                DatePosted = '$t',
                                DateExp = '$_SESSION[AccountExpDate]',
                                FeaturedStatus = '$_POST[sp]' ";
//echo $q1;
    mysql_query($q1) or die(mysql_error());

}

//get the posted offers
$q1 = "select count(*) from class_catalog where MemberID = '$_SESSION[MemberID]' ";
$r1 = mysql_query($q1) or die(mysql_error());
$a1 = mysql_fetch_array($r1);



header("location:AddAsset.php");

exit();

?>
```

The mySql insert function isn't adding anything also it return success to me , I've tried using INSERT ... Values but what it done was overwtiting existing value ( i.e make 1 entry and overwties it everytime).

I am using PHP 4.4.9 and MySql 4

I tried to add from Phpmyadmin and it is working also it was working after installation but after i quit the browser and made a new account to test it it is not working but the old ones is working ! you can see it here http://bemidjiclassifieds.com/ 
try to login with usr:openbook pass:mohamed24 and you can see it will be working but any new account won't work!

Comment: Take a look in your database and see what data has been added. You can use something like phpMyAdmin to do so or just use raw SQL commands.

Comment: Is your MySQL server configured to not autocommit?

Comment: how do you know it returns success?

Comment: `INSERT` should never overwrite, MySql uses `UPDATE` and `REPLACE` queries for that. If I were you I'd go back to using the correct `INSERT` statement and post that issue instead.

Comment: I tried to add from Phpmyadmin and it is working also it was working after installation but after i quit the browser and made a new account to test it it is not working but the old ones is working ! you can see it here http://bemidjiclassifieds.com/

Comment: try the login with usr:openbook pass:mohamed24 and you will see it is working but if new account is created it willn't work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe $_POST[s1] is not set or you are inserting into a different database than you are watching.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST[s1]))
```

should probably be

```
if(isset($_POST['s1']))
```

(note the quotes). Also, it's best to NOT depend on a field being present in the submitted data to check if you're doing a POSt. the 100% reliable method is

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { ... }
```

As well, you're not checking if the file  uploads succeeded. Each file should be checked like this:

```
foreach($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key => $name) {
   if ($_FILES['images']['error'][$key] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
       echo "File #$key failed to upload, error code {$_FILES['images']['error'][$key]}";
   }
   ...
}
```

Don't use `copy()` to move uploaded files. There's a `move_uploaded_files()` function for that, which does some extra sanity checking to make sure nothing's tampered with the file between the time the upload finished and your script tries to move it.

Comment: I tried this but it is the same , also it was working after installation but after i quit the browser and made a new account to test it it is not working but the old ones is working ! you can see it here http://bemidjiclassifieds.com/